# How to replace <br /> tag name to white space in sanitize-html JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sanitize, strip-tags, html-sanitizing

I have a string of HTML like:

```
"<p>Hello world!<br/>I am here</p>"
```

I want to get the output result after replaced:

```
"<p>Hello world! I am here</p>"
```

How I can do it with sanitize-html package?

Comment: Please provide additional details. Do you mean an NPM package called `sanitize-html` ? What have you tried? Are you writing in javascript/nodejs or are you writing in Ruby as the `sanitize` tag might suggest?

Comment: what about: string.replace("<br/>", " ");    in node.js ?

Comment: Here's NPM package "sanitize-html" i am saying: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html. I using it in Node.js to remove all strip tags and replacement to white-space if tag name is <br/> tag.

Answer (score -1):

Source: [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

```
const result = 'lorem<br />ipsum<br />hello'.replaceAll('<br />', ' ');
// result = 'lorem ipsum hello';
```

Comment: OP specifically requests to an approach using a specific library.